# Animation: scaling an object on 2 different axes without influencing eachother

Tags: animation, faces

In Animation I want to animate an upsidedown 'L'. So scaling a cube along 2 axis. First up (Z) then sideways (X). In frame 1 I start with a cube. In frame 100 I have scaled it along the Z-axis. That works fine. After that I made a loop cut to create a face that will extrude sideways. I want to extrude that face along the X-axis from frame 100 to 200. I can't get it to work. At playback the X-scaling starts also in frame 1 instead of starting from frame 100 to 200.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try it with the *Animall* addon: create this mesh, in the *N panel > Animate*, activate *Key > Points > Location* and at frame 1 press on *Insert Key*:

[image]

At frame 20 (or whatever) move the top vertices and create a keyframe again:

[image]

At frame 40 move the inset face:

[image]

At frame 60 move down the top faces:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have read about the animall add on. I wil try that. I just thought that I could realize this with the standard Blender setup. (BTW, the last screenshot is the start of my animation.)